# R export graph to pdf with page labels and import into LaTeX using page labels

Tags: r, pdf, latex

I was wondering if it is possible to set page labels in PDFs exported from R and import the PDF page as an image using said labels into LaTeX?

What I want to do is:

1. export several graphs from R to a single multi-page PDF file
2. label the pages in the PDF

**Idea:**

```
PDF("multipage.pdf")
  graph_object_1 (label="bubblechart")
  graph_object_2 (label="bargraph")
  graph_object_3 (label="scatterplot")
dev.off()
```

3. import as graph into LaTeX using the label instead of a page number

`\includegraphics[page={bargraph}]{multipage}`

I am aware that I can access pages using the respective page number. But it is common that the graphs change over time, more are added, some are removed. And adapting the page numbers in the TeX file every time would be painful.

I know about Sweave and knitR but my co-authors don't use R and they are therefore not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you want to use a single pdf file. Why not

```
pdf("bubblechart.pdf")
...
dev.off()
pdf("bargraph.pdf")
...
dev.off()
```

and then

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{bubblechart}
\end{figure}
```

and so forth... 
LaTeX would do all the numbering and you have maximal flexibility...

Comment: There is a lot mailing going on and I am fed up with zipping everything and mailing it over. And, yes, I am aware that this is a bad system, but author 1 uses google drive, author 2 dropbox, author 3 github and apparently noone is willing to switch. This would make it possible to send 3 files (graphics pdf, Latex source, Bibtex library) or only the single graphics file to update all graphs. As an example, for the last project the graphics folder contained > 60 graphs.